# How to Add Custom variables to SendGrid email via API C# and Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendgrid

I am trying to figure out how to add variables to existing template (example: Web Link Or Name dynamically) which has been created in sendgrid template engine, I am unsure how to do this using the SendGrid C# .NET libraries. I am wondering if anyone could help me.

```
// Create the email object first, then add the properties.
SendGridMessage myMessage = new SendGridMessage();

myMessage.AddTo("test@test.com");
myMessage.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com", "Mr test");
myMessage.Subject = " ";

var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
myMessage.Html = "<p></p> ";

myMessage.EnableTemplate("<p> <% body %> Hello</p>");
myMessage.EnableTemplateEngine("9386b483-8ad4-48c2-9ee3-afc7618eb56a");
var identifiers = new Dictionary<String, String>();
identifiers["USER_FULLNAME"] = "Jimbo Jones";
identifiers["VERIFICATION_URL"] = "www.google.com";
myMessage.AddUniqueArgs(identifiers);

// Create credentials, specifying your user name and password.
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
// Create an Web transport for sending email.
var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
// Send the email.
transportWeb.Deliver(myMessage);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
replacementKey = "*|VERIFICATION_URL|*";
substitutionValues = new List<string> { VERIFICATION_URL };

myMessage.AddSubstitution(replacementKey, substitutionValues);
```

Comment: You had to remove something from your code in question?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.?

Comment: Disregard my comment, I resolved my problem. Thanks,

Comment: Instead of using "identifiers" and AddUniqueArgs (which are used to add extra fields to the email for identification), Jimbo is using AddSubstitution, which substitutes text in a template.

Answer (score 10):

My Email

```
Hello -REP-

<%body%>

Fotter
```

My C# Code

```
myMessage.AddSubstitution("-REP-", substitutionValues);
```

Works PERFECT!!!

Answer (score 3):

I've used the following approach.  Note you have to provide the `mail.Text` and `mail.Html` values - I use the empty string and `<p></p>` tag as seen in the example.  Your SendGrid template also still must contain the default `<%body%>` and `<%subject%>` tokens, although they will be replaced with the actual subject and body value specified in the `mail.Text` and `mail.Html` properties.

```
public void Send(string from, string to, string subject, IDictionary<string, string> replacementTokens, string templateId)
{
  var mail = new SendGridMessage
  {
    From = new MailAddress(from)
  };

  mail.AddTo(to);
  mail.Subject = subject;

  // NOTE: Text/Html and EnableTemplate HTML are not really used if a TemplateId is specified
  mail.Text = string.Empty;
  mail.Html = "<p></p>";
  mail.EnableTemplate("<%body%>");

  mail.EnableTemplateEngine(templateId);

  // Add each replacement token
  foreach (var key in replacementTokens.Keys)
  {
    mail.AddSubstitution(
      key,
      new List<string>
        {
          replacementTokens[key]
        });
  }

  var transportWeb = new Web("THE_AUTH_KEY");
  var result = transportWeb.DeliverAsync(mail);
}
```

It can then be called like this:

```
Send(
"noreply@example.com", 
"TO_ADDRESS", 
"THE SUBJECT", 
new Dictionary<string, string> { 
{ "@Param1!", "Parameter 1" }, 
{ "@Param2!", "Parameter 2" } }, 
"TEMPLATE_GUID");
```

Answer (score 3):

After did lots of RND. My below code is working fine & Tested as well.

```
            SendGridMessage myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
            myMessage.AddTo(email);
            myMessage.AddBcc("MyEmail@gmail.com");
            myMessage.AddBcc("EmailSender_CC@outlook.com");
            myMessage.From = new MailAddress("SenderEmail@outlook.com", "DriverPickup");
            //myMessage.Subject = "Email Template Test 15.";
            myMessage.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", GetMessageHeaderForWelcome("MyEmail@Gmail.com", callBackUrl));
            myMessage.Html = string.Format(" ");

            // Create an Web transport for sending email.
            var transportWeb = new Web(SendGridApiKey);

            // Send the email, which returns an awaitable task.
            transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
```

I have created Separate method for getting JSON header

```
private static string GetMessageHeaderForWelcome(string email, string callBackUrl)
    {

        var header = new Header();
        //header.AddSubstitution("{{FirstName}}", new List<string> { "Dilip" });
        //header.AddSubstitution("{{LastName}}", new List<string> { "Nikam" });
        header.AddSubstitution("{{EmailID}}", new List<string> { email });
        header.AddSubstitution("-VERIFICATIONURL-", new List<string>() { callBackUrl });
        //header.AddSubstitution("*|VERIFICATIONURL|*", new List<string> { callBackUrl });
        //header.AddSubstitution("{{VERIFICATIONURL}}", new List<string> { callBackUrl });
        header.AddFilterSetting("templates", new List<string> { "enabled" }, "1");
        header.AddFilterSetting("templates", new List<string> { "template_id" }, WelcomeSendGridTemplateID);
        return header.JsonString();

    }
```

Below code I have used in my HTML Sendgrid template.

```
<div>Your {{EmailID}} register. Please <a class="btn-primary" href="-VERIFICATIONURL-">Confirm email address</a></div>
```

In case if any query please let me know.

For inline HTML replace you need to use -YourKeyForReplace- & for text replace you need to use {{UserKeyForReplace}}

Comment: Can we create object of SendGridMessage with Using statement in C#?